# ¿Como generar una matriz con una lista que contiene datos?

Tags: python

Cordial saludo.

tengo una lista de la siguiente forma.

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

y quiero generar una matriz 4x3 con esa lista y con esos datos, de tal
 forma que me quede algo así:

```
 M=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

gracias por su atención prestada.

Comment: ¿Alguna restricción?, ¿qué pasa si la cantidad de elementos no es múltipli de 3?

Comment: no ninguna restricción, que se genere una matriz, solo que el numero de columnas sea la misma para todas la filas es decir puede si tiene 6 filas que cada fila tenga dos columnas, si tiene 3 filas que cada fila tenga 4 columnas y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [numpy.reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> np.array(L).reshape(4,3)

array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Tener en cuenta que para poder usar esta función el número total de elementos en el array deben permanecer iguales.

Otra forma que no necesita numpy:

```
>>> L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> fila = 4
>>> col = 3
>>> M = [L[col*i : col*(i+1)] for i in range(row)]

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: y si tengo muchos datos y solo conozco el numero de columnas pero no se cuantas lineas podrían salir, como se soluciona si es posible.

Comment: Luego de obtener la lista, saca su tamaño con `len(L)` y lo divides por el número de columnas. Es decir, para sacar las filas utiliza algo así: `row = len(L) / col`

Comment: O mejor, pon `-1` en las filas y se ajustará automáticamente (`np.reshape(-1,3)`)

Answer (score 1):

Se puede aplicar el siguiente truco *funcional*:

```
from itetools import zip_longest

L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
ncols = 4

args = [iter(L)]*ncols
M = list(zip_longest(*args))
```

**Explicación**:

1. se crea un *iterador* a partir de la lista: `iter(L)`
2. se *duplica* el iterador tantas veces como columnas queremos: `[iter(L)]*ncols`. Todos los items de esta lista son el mismo iterador, por lo que si ahora hiciéramos un `list([iter(L)]*ncols)` obtendríamos los primeros elementos del iterador, que son los primeros `ncols` items de la lista `L` (`L[0:ncols]`)
3. `zip_longest` combina listas como hace la función `zip`, pero rellenando las listas más cortas hasta alcanzar la lista más larga (Se le podría pasar un argumento para indicar con qué valor rellenar las listas más cortas).
4. se pasa la lista de iteradores a la función `zip_longest` como argumento múltiple. Es equivalente a si hiciéramos `zip_longest(it, it,...,it)` tantas veces como sea el valor de `ncols`. De este modo, se pilla en orden un valor de cada argumento para crear la primera fila, se continua con el segundo, y así hasta que no quedan más. Como todos los argumentos son el mismo iterador, se irá extrayendo valores de él hasta agotarlo.

Tal como he dicho, si el número de items no fueran suficientes para rellenar la última fila, se podría indicar a `zip_longest` para que lo hiciera con un valor por defecto:

```
# para rellenar con ceros
M = list(zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=0))
```